# Make [kwargs] a synonym of [keyword-argument]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I'll let the info for [kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kwargs) speak for itself:

> Common abbreviation for "keyword arguments".

Link for convenience: [keyword-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyword-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

This wasn’t even something the community could have done, as there were only 250-ish [keyword-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyword-argument) questions and circa 500 [kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kwargs) posts. The UI then refuses to let you create a synonym.

But the mapping absolutely makes sense even when you consider that in Python the subject is often really about the `**kwargs` catch-all syntax. For that there is the [argument-unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argument-unpacking) tag as well, and most questions concerning that specific area already use that tag anyway.

So I suggested the link in the opposite direction then used a mod-only feature to swap the synonym connection before turning the suggested connection into an actual synonym.